# Java 8 retrieve Map's values into an array with stream and filter

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Would someone help me with getting the array of the map values with stream and filtering?

```
public class TheMap extends HashMap<String, String> {
    public TheMap(String name, String title) {
        super.put("name", name);
        super.put("title", title);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Map<Long, Map<String, String>>map = new HashMap<>();            

        map.put(0L, null);
        map.put(1L, new TheMap("jane", "engineer"));
        map.put(2L, new TheMap("john", "engineer"));
        map.put(3L, new TheMap(null, "manager"));
        map.put(4L, new TheMap("who", null));
        map.put(5L, new TheMap(null, null));
    }
}
```

The result that I am looking for is an `ArrayList<TheMap>` with only these two entries:

```
TheMap("jane", "engineer")
TheMap("john", "engineer")
```

Basically, retrieve `TheMap` with `none-null` name and `title`.

Comment: This is weird, you're putting an overridden Map into another map? Are you sure you want to do this? Don't you want a bean with just name and title properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an arrayList of `TheMap`, try the following way:

```
ArrayList<TheMap> as = map.values()
   .stream()
   .filter(v -> v != null && v.get("name") != null && v.get("title") != null)
   .map(m -> (TheMap)m)
   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

Comment: there are not guarantees that the returned List is actually an ArrayList, so your cast might break in a future release. `Collectors.toCollection` is what you want in this case

Comment: @Holger. Sorry, I should have paid more attention on the filter to see that it was only filtering out the null values but not the key / values inside the values. See my edit.

Comment: @Eugene, as per the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#Collectors.toList%28%29) of `Collectors.toList`, it does in fact instantiate and return an `ArrayList`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @VHS you are not missing anything, but that is exactly what makes this an implementation detail that might change. Look at the javadoc of `toList` and the guarantees that it does *not make*.

Comment: @Eugene, thanks for a nice suggestion. I edited my answer to use `toCollection` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = 
        map.values().stream().filter(v -> 
                              v != null && 
                              !v.entrySet().isEmpty() &&
                              !v.containsValue(null)).
        collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what’s the point of `v.entrySet().isEmpty()`? That doesn’t produce different results than `v.isEmpty()`. Besides that, empty maps are not within the OP’s problem description anyway.

Comment: both produce the same result.  my original problem statement did not include the empty Map, but it is good to have.  this way, when I add a constructor TheMap() {}, the logic would still work.

Comment: Can I post a follow-up question here. I have code to search the List<TheMap> based on Map<String, String>.  Just like to know if my code is good.  Map<String, String> srch = new HashMap<>();
        srch.put("name",  "jane"); List<Map<String, String>>fnd = list.stream().filter(e -> { boolean f = true; for (Entry<String, String>s: srch.entrySet()) f &= (e.get(s.getKey()) == s.getValue()); return f;}).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Please, post a new question or update this one. As a comment, it's difficult to read your new question